# Regex to add a CSS condition if a particular condition is satisfied

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

It's a bit complicated.
I would like to write a regexp to add `border:0;display:block` if the `$subject` doesn't contain, or if `$subject`'s border doesn't equal `0 nor display:block;`

for instance, if the `$subject` is:

**Case 1:**

```
color:white
```

after `preg_replace` if will return

```
color:white;border:0;display:block
```

**Case 2:**

```
color:white;border:1px;
```

after preg_replace if will return

```
color:white;border:0;display:block
```

**Case 3:**

```
color:white;display:inline
```

after `preg_replace` if will return

```
color:white;display:block;border:0;
```

**Case 4:**

```
{empty}
```

after `preg_replace` if will return

```
border:0;display:block;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about removing `border`, `display` attribute, then append attribute you want?

```
function no_border($css)
{
    $css = preg_replace('/;?\s*(border|display)\s*:[^;]+;?/', '', $css);
    return ltrim(rtrim($css, ';') . ';border:0;display:block;', ';');
}

no_border('color:white');                // "color:white;border:0;display:block;"
no_border('color:white;border:1px;');    // "color:white;border:0;display:block;"
no_border('color:white;display:inline'); // "color:white;border:0;display:block;"
no_border('');                           // "border:0;display:block;"
```

Comment: $css = preg_replace('/;?\s*(border|display)\s*:\b[^;]+;?/', '', $css);